# how to exclude UnauthorizedAccessException using framework 3.5

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, frameworks

hye, I have created an application that will list down all file in folder and subfolder but I got this error "UnauthorizedAccessException" when trying to listdown file in c:windows. I'm using a foreach loop, to counter the error, I have catch the error but it will end the application. how can I skip this error and move on to another file. this is the code that I have made.

```
try
        {
            //linecount2 = Directory.GetFiles(path2).Count();
            //textBox1.Text = linecount2.ToString();

            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path2, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                currentpath = file;
                Directory.GetAccessControl(file);
                DateTime creationdate = File.GetCreationTime(file);
                DateTime modidate = File.GetLastWriteTime(file);
                textBox1.Text = "[" + file + "]" + "[" + creationdate + "]" + "[" + creationdate + "]";
                ReportLog(savefile);
            }
        }
        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "[" + readpath + "]" + "[No path available]" + "[]";
            ReportLog(savefile);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "[" + currentpath + "]" + "[Unauthorized Access]" + "[]";
            ReportLog(savefile);
        }
```

if possible I would like to include the file that hidden. that would really help.

Comment: Put the try/catch block inside the for loop.

Comment: does not work as the error is the loop itself

Comment: Your problem is "SearchOption.AllDirectories" parameter. Try to use recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that any error causes the code to jump out of the loop. Instead, put the error catching inside the for loop:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path2, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    try
    {
        currentpath = file;
        Directory.GetAccessControl(file);
        DateTime creationdate = File.GetCreationTime(file);
        DateTime modidate = File.GetLastWriteTime(file);
        textBox1.Text = "[" + file + "]" + "[" + creationdate + "]" + "[" + creationdate + "]";
        ReportLog(savefile);
    }
    catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "[" + readpath + "]" + "[No path available]" + "[]";
        ReportLog(savefile);
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "[" + currentpath + "]" + "[Unauthorized Access]" + "[]";
        ReportLog(savefile);
    }
}
```

There are some other issues with your code though, and the code in the loop doesn't appear to do anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use recursive function like this one:

```
public static List<string> GetRecords(string path)
{
    List<string> records;
    try
    {
        records = Directory.GetFiles(path)
            .Select(
                o => string.Format("[{0}][{1}][{2}]", o, File.GetCreationTime(o), File.GetLastWriteTime(o)))
            .ToList();
        foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
        {
            records.AddRange(GetRecords(directory));
        }
        return records;
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        return new List<string> {string.Format("[{0}][Unauthorized Access][]", path)};
    }
    catch (DirectoryNotFoundException)
    {
        return new List<string> { string.Format("[{0}][No path available][]", path) };
    }
}
```